# typescript function runs fine when i provide ref to object but it gives error when i add additional props to object and pass it as a value

Tags: typescript, interface

**i have a function called *sayMyName* that receives an argument of type User**

when I pass a user as reference it works fine -

```
interface User{
  firstName:string;
  lastName:string;
}

function sayMyName(user:User){
  console.log(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName );
}

const user = {firstName: "john", lastName: "snow", age: 22}

sayMyName(user);
```

but if I pass a object to *sayMyName* on the go as -

```
sayMyName({firstName: "john", lastName:"snow", age:22});
```

it gives me error

> Argument of type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number;
> }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.   Object literal may
> only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type
> 'User'.

what exactly is breaking my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Answer (score 1):

**@Vineet Desai** is right, this is because of `excess-property-checks`.

Please treat my answer as a small extension to his answer.

If you want to bypass this error you can try to add extra generic for `user` argument:

```js
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

function sayMyName<T extends User>(user: T) {
  console.log(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName);
}

const user = { firstName: "john", lastName: "snow", age: 22 }

sayMyName(user); // ok


sayMyName({ firstName: "john", lastName: "snow", age: 22 }); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnIzBTpgBycAthAFzKlSgDmA3PsgDZykXV0PM2AX1y4YAVxAIwwAPYh6cAJ4BZJbwgAeACrIIAD0ggAJujSYoAPgAU4i3W0BKHOwTz0sjhAB0HWU1sLbyIScioUAGpkACIY5Ci7aF9uMOpHYVE3EFJkRKhkAF4cQmIecLpogCtZAAsQaIAaThSNCvQQWQB3RuQ4JlpkACZB5BFcdGU1DUDodOQAennkWQBrUXHJ9XDrbBLQ1pjqup6uMr4Y9q6evoHh0bnF5bWgA)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your method based on any object containing some keys, then define it like this

```
function sayMyName({firstName, lastName}){
  console.log(firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

This will work the same way for:

```
const tmpUser: User = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}; 
const tmpRecord: Record<string, string> = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"};
```